# git-http-push failed error on pushing repo to remote server

Tags: git, apache, ldap

I have setup a bare git repo on my laptop and cloned a copy of this repo another laptop.
I can successfully clone/pull changes made to bare repo.

However i cannot PUSH any changes to the repo.
It always results in GIT-HTTP-PUSH Failed

```
[core]
repositoryformatversion = 0
filemode = false
bare = false
logallrefupdates = true
symlinks = false
ignorecase = true
hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
[remote "origin"]
url = https://`10.2.80.235`/htdocs/BPDirect.git
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[merge]
summary = true
[branch "master"]
remote = origin
merge = refs/heads/master
[gui]
wmstate = normal
geometry = 887x427+175+175 171 192
```

Comment: May i know your trails (commands used till now). So, that i will be able to help you out.

Comment: git clone https://10.2.80.235/htdocs/repo.git, 
made changes in files, 
git add file, 
git commit -m "message", 
git push.